# Efficient socket I/O using Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)

Tags: .net, sockets, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm working on a client application that uses raw TCP sockets for communication to a central server. Application messages are serialized and then length-prefixed to create frames that are passed into the TCP stream.

One classic method for handling this is to directly invoke Receive or BeginReceive on the socket class, deserialize the message on the callback, pass the message into a separate queue for processing by another thread, then have the callback begin another receive on the socket again.

A naive implementation of this approach isn't ideal for me - it tightly couples message serialization and deserialization to the socket and requires quite a bit of "plumbing" to get the queue to play nice across different threads/callbacks. It's also somewhat of a leaky abstraction - it requires the calling code to have knowledge of the underlying socket, rather than a 'data flow' of input and output messages.

Given that I'm working entirely within .NET 4.5, wrapping the Socket's Begin and End async methods using TPL (TaskFactory.FromAsync) is an obvious choice. However, I'm unclear how to proceed from this point for a number of reasons:

1. I need an asynchronous "task" that never completes to receive the data. As long as the socket is connected, I would like a stream of messages being processed. Any interruption (disconnection, socket error, or cancellation request) would be an exception, rather than a traditional Task completion. According to Stephen Toub (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/02/10218999.aspx), I should always complete my tasks. This creates a bit of a problem - a socket receive never completes in the traditional sense. Stephen seems to contradict himself slightly in his "Awaiting Socket Operations" post, where he shows a socket read that never completes without a socket error (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx).
2. I need a method of synchronously "queuing" data to be sent. A caller should be able to send a message to be transmitted out without blocking, and the messages should be transmitted sequentially across the socket. In other words, only one send at a time on the socket itself due to the message framing. Is TPL dataflow a good fit, or is there a different queuing pattern I should use?
3. I would like a clean separation of concerns between message serialization and message transmission.

I haven't seen many examples with this type of strategy, only "direct" Socket I/O or trivial implementations. My intuition tells me TPL Dataflow is a good fit, given that serialization and deserialization can be pipelined.

I'm unclear how to bridge an effectively endless chain of Receive tasks to TPL Dataflow or something similar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

At this time, there are no examples of good approaches for this. Once you get a solution working, I'd recommend publishing it somewhere.

> 1. I need an asynchronous "task" that never completes to receive the data...

I disagree with the statement "a socket receive never completes in the traditional sense". The lower-level "receive" operation (e.g., a `FromAsync` wrapper around `BeginReceive`/`EndReceive` or Toub's `ReceiveAsync`) returns a `Task` that will complete when there is data available, the socket is closed, or there is an error. The higher-level "receiver" operation (e.g., `ReadAsync` [from Toub's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx)) will complete when the socket is closed or there is an error.

You *can* have `Task`s that could take an indefinite amount of time to complete, but as long as they *do* complete that's fine. What Toub was pointing out in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/02/10218999.aspx) is that your `Task`s should complete *eventually* (handling error situations in particular). This is different than Rx's approach, where it is perfectly valid to have an observable that never produces data and never ends.

> 2. I need a method of synchronously "queuing" data to be sent...

Technically, it's "serialized" ("in order"), not "synchronous". The ideal solution would be asynchronously serialized. There's a few approaches for this.

I would say that TPL Dataflow is a good fit. Note that there are actually two logical "streams" per socket (read and write are independent). I've had some success with a Dataflow-based socket wrapper, but haven't had the time to make it production-quality. The API is rather awkward due to the two streams (each of my pluggable "blocks" have to have two TPL Dataflow blocks, one for input and one for output).

Another approach is [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx). Rx has a higher learning curve than plain `Task`s or TPL Dataflow, but provides quite a bit of power (and efficiency). I played around with Rx-based sockets a couple years ago, but never got anything working. The documentation and examples for Rx are much better these days, so I would consider it a viable option today.

There's also the approach of just using `async` methods directly. You would use synchronization instead of a queue. E.g., you could use a `SemaphoreSlim` to ensure only one of your `SendAsync` methods can run at a time for a given socket. However, that does change the semantics, pushing some of the "serialization-ness" up to your calling code: instead of a simple enqueue-and-complete-task (which would always complete synchronously unless you hit your send throttling), you have an asynchronously-wait-to-send-and-then-complete-task (which would almost always asynchronously wait). You could mitigate this by building an `async` producer/consumer queue ([like the one I wrote](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncProducerConsumerQueue)), but then you have a *separate* consumer `Task` that you need to track, and at that point you're just rewriting TPL Dataflow.

> I'm unclear how to "bridge" an effectively "endless" chain of Receive tasks to TPL Dataflow or something similar.

There isn't a good built-in way to do this.

A simple solution is to have a "Receiver" `Task` that is solely responsible for pushing data into the TPL Dataflow pipeline. However, you'd have to monitor that `Task` to ensure the pipeline isn't abandoned if some error happens, and you'd need a way to shut it down cleanly.

I did write up a [`FuncBlock` type](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FuncBlock) to handle this situation (with the idea of using it for socket reads and other I/O-based inputs to Dataflows). It took a while to iron out all the semantics of how the `async` method and the Dataflow block interact (particularly around cancellation/errors/completion), but I think it would be useful. I'd appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Fantastic info. Do you feel it would be acceptable in terms of API design to have the "outer" (indefinite) receive method return a Task flagged as "long-running" and never have it transition into the completed state? (ie/ the task would always ultimately end in Cancelled or Faulted, never Completed - a socket close is a form of fault). The other option would be to expose the same "single receive per message" semantics to the outer class, and build an adapter to connect it into a TPL dataflow buffer somehow. The adapter would manage the "lifetime" of the receive.

Comment: As long as the `Task` completes, that's fine (it doesn't have to ever have the chance of completing *successfully*). `LongRunning` doesn't apply to `async` tasks; don't worry about it. At some point you'd need an adapter (like `FuncBlock`), IMO you may as well just move it as close to `Socket` as possible and use Dataflow blocks for everything else.